# Is a negative z-index not working in Safari?

Tags: html, css

I have a position fixed element with `z-index: -1` and in **Safari** the `z-index` seems to be ignored. why?

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Yes safari has issues w/ negative z-index in some edge cases (like in association w/ `transition` and other stuff).

Comment: yes I'm using CSS transition in some elements... I will look it up